# access objects stored in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to create a new array with just the object values of myArray. My code below returns newArray with both Objects stored, but I am stuck on how to get the 'values' out and put them into the array. I am used to for-in on Objects, but not sure how to access objects when they are stored in an Array.

```
var myArray = [{first: 'michael', last: 'jordan'}, {first: 'brett', last: 'favre'}];
var myFunc = function (values) {
    newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) {
        newArray.push(values);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: What's the expected output? `[ 'michael', 'jordan', 'brett', 'favre' ]`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wvg8H/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myFunc = function (values) {
    newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) {
        for(var e in values[i]) {
            newArray.push(values[i][e]);
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Qb3g/)

Note that this method is 'shallow'—that is, it will only get values one-level deep. If you had a structure like `[{foo:{bar:'baz'}}]`, the result would be `[{bar:'baz'}]`.

Comment: I see that working, thank you. Do I always need to write a for-in loop to get access to the objects in an array?

Comment: @jstone Um no, if you know ahead of time what the properties you want to get are, you could have just done `newArray.push(values[i].first, values[i].last)` instead of that entire inner loop.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this example.

```
var array = ['a','b','c','d'];
```

The index of 'a' is 0
The index of 'b' is 1
and so forth...

Therefore:

```
array[0] = 'a'
```

Next example:

```
var array = [ { foo: 'bar' }, { hello: 'world' } ];
```

The index of the first object is 0
The index of the second object is 1

Therefore:

```
array[0] = { foo: 'bar' }
```

To access a property of that object, you can do this:

```
array[0]['foo'] = 'bar';
```

So, you can do something like this, to iterate over the members of an object, when that object is inside of an array:

```
var array = [ { foo: 'bar' }, { hello: 'world' } ],
    newArray = [];

var i, len = array.length;

for( i=0; i<len; i++ ) {

    for ( e in array[i] ) {

        newArray.push(array[i][e]);

    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**:
     newArray = ['bar', 'world'];

Answer (score 1):

This example uses the relatively new `Object.keys()` and `Array.reduce()`:

```
var values = myArray.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    return prev.concat(Object.keys(current).map(function(key) { 
        return current[key]; 
    }));
}, []);
```